# Firebase crashlytics not getting reported after adding "tools:node=”replace" this line in manifiest

Tags: java, android, crashlytics

I added firebase crashlytics in Gradle. But in my project, multiple third-party libraries were included. So multiple AndroidManifest and in the main manifest. I added one line `tools:node="replace"` but somehow it blocks reporting crashes on firebase crashlytics. if I remove this line then merge conflicts get occurred and multiple copies of the application get created like 3 copies.
I tried to use `tools:node="merge"` instead of `tools:node="replace"` but the same merge manifest conflicts occurred.

> Error: Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:64:9-36 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-35 value=(true). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:62:5-1207:19 to override. 18_Oct_Android11.vodafoneEKYC main manifest (this file), line 63

Can you help me out?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually, the problem is I want to report a crash on firebase crashlytics but the crash does not get reported because of this line  tools:node="replace" which is in a manifest file if I removed this lie then crash get reported but issue occurred in the merge manifiest file